# Ruby-Gem celluloid version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

when I put gem list,I found that the **celluloid** has 
    a version (0.14.1, 0.12.4)
    I didn't understand what's the version of celluloid? 
    If i want to return to the version 0.12.4 how can i do . 
    [List of gems from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5CHi.png)

Answer (score 0):

if I had to guess, would use whatever the latest version is, and if specified in `Gemfile`, whatever version is specified in `Gemfile`

also, guessing it had been showing all versions of which it had been aware

also, guessing in a `Gemfile` could specify:

```
gem celluloid, '0.12.4'
```

also, http://bundler.io/gemfile.html, in case that may be of interest

Comment: yes i found in Gemfile.lock = > celluloid (0.12.4) . i had a problem when i would like to deploy in server there's an  error : You have already activated celluloid 0.14.1, but your Gemfile requires celluloid 0.12.4 .